# Cubic polynomial - radical expression of roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, roots, radicals

Let $f=X^3+X^2-2X-1$ be a polynomial with the three roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$ with $x_1=2\text{cos}(\frac{2 \pi}{7})$. We define $z:=(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)$.

I want to find a radical expression for $x_1=2\text{cos}(\frac{2 \pi}{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}[z]$.

I found some information [here](http://www.literka.addr.com/mathcountry/algebra/trigvalues/values07.htm) and [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath186.htm) and with a computer program I calculated that $$x_1=\frac{1}{3}\left(-1+\frac{7^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} (1+3 i \sqrt{3})}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2} (1+3 i \sqrt{3})}\right).$$

I think this expression is not the one I am searching for but I wonder how I can find it by calculating it in a correct way (without using a program).

Finally, what's the importance of $z$ and $\mathbb{Q}[z]$? Is there a way to calculate $z$? Using a computer program I found out that $z \in \mathbb{Q}$, which confuses me.

Answer (score 3):

> *I wonder how I can find it by calculating it in a correct way (without using a program).*

The [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) has been around for the last $500$ years. Feel free to use it.

---

> *I think this expression is not the one I am searching for*.

Why ? Because it contains in its expression the square root of $-1$, despite being obviously a real number, and not an imaginary one ? If so, then please see [casus irreducibilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

---

> *Using a computer program I found out that $z\in\mathbb Q$, which confuses me.*

In that case, read [Niven's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven's_theorem), and let the confusion dissipate.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check your links. I think I am not allowed to use the cubic formula. Anyway, what is the cheapest way to calculate $z$? It looks to be a bit expensive.

Comment: Are you asking me how to numerically compute by hand the value of $x_1$ up to a certain number of decimal places with the least effort, by using the fact that it is a root of a given cubic equation ? If so, then there are plenty of [numerical methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) which you might employ to that end.

Comment: No, I want to do it per hand-calculating. I think the best method is using the complex forms.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by hand calculating.

Comment: Without using a computer.

Comment: Did I tell you to use a computer ?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the complex expressions, the three roots are given by$$x_1=\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{7} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(3
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$x_2=-\frac{1}{3}-\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(3
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{7} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(3 \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$
$$x_3=-\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(3
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{7} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(3 \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$ and, effectively, $x_1=2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}  {7}$. I suppose that you see the common stucture which appears in the roots.

**Added later to this answer**

Brute force gives for the roots $$x_1=\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+\frac{7^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+3 i
   \sqrt{3}\right)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2} \left(1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)}\right)$$  $$x_2=-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{7^{2/3} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{3\ 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{1+3 i
   \sqrt{3}}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2} \left(1+3 i
   \sqrt{3}\right)}$$ $$x_3=-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{7^{2/3} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)}{3\ 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{1+3 i
   \sqrt{3}}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2} \left(1+3 i
   \sqrt{3}\right)}$$

Comment: I thought in a radical expression there shouldn't be any $\text{sin},\text{cos}$ or $\text{tan}$ functions. And how can I see that $z \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: How can I find the complex expressions of $x_2$ and $x_3$?

Comment: I shall add these awful expressions in my answer.

Comment: The problem is that only $x_1$ is given. So I don't know how to find $x_2$ and $x_3$ by hand-calculating; as you said - awful expressions.

Comment: Under which form is given $x_1$ to you ? If you know $x_1$ and you know that $x_1+x_2+x_3=-1$ and $x_1x_2x_3=1$, you have two equations for two unknowns $x_1,x_2$. Fou cane eliminate $x_3$ from the first, replace in the second and solve a quadratic equation in $x_2$.

Comment: I only know that $x_1=2\text{cos}(\frac{2 \pi}{7})$.

Comment: I see, you used Vieta's formulas. Is this correct?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: Then solve the two equations I wrote. Sorry for some typo's ! You know $x_1$ and you know the sum and the product of the roots. Eliminate $x_3$ from the sum; this let you with the product as a single quadratic equation in $x_2$.

Comment: Yes ! Vieta for sure. This is the only way.